# `app.use(express.static` seems to not working if app - is subapplication

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, subapplication

I try to do something like this:

```
var main = express();
main.use(express.static(path.resolve('./asset')));
main.route('someroute', someHandle);
var app = express();
app.use(express.static(path.resolve('./asset')));
app.route('someroute', someHandle);
main.use('/app', app);
```

assets `/asset/someasset.js` served well, but  `/app/asset/someasset.js` not returned (404), paths resolving to right folders.

I tried `app.use('/app', express.static(path.resolve('./asset')));` - not work, but `main.use('/app', express.static(path.resolve('./asset')));` - works!

Is there some limitation to use `express.static` with mounted subapp?

UPD:

I try use mounted app as described in http://expressjs.com/ru/4x/api.html#express app.mountPath  expecting that all features of express mounted as sub application should work in it, and as stumbled on static problem i would like to know is there are limitations in this use case? and what they could be?

Comment: Well, because you're using an express app as a middleware for another express app. I doesn't work. Take a look at middleware: http://expressjs.com/guide/using-middleware.html

Comment: @Peyman, does it mean that when using express as a middleware it can not use other middlewares? i didn't find that following the link you gave

Comment: That's a good question, I don't know, I think you might be able to but what I'm sure of is that you can't do main.use('/app', app). since *app* is an express app instance while it should be a middleware. express.static is a middleware.

Comment: express apps themselves are middleware, fyi @Peyman

Comment: @DanPantry so is this a valid statement then: main.use('/app', express());

Answer (score 2):

Edit: Your use of path.resolve is all wrong.

```js
path.resolve('./asset')
```

in both cases resolves to the same folder.  The mounting point of the middleware only affects the url and not the directory folder.  Rewrite your code as suggested below and everything will work as advertised

My guess is express.static is still operating on the original path.  So try this

```js
var main = express();
main.use(express.static(path.resolve('./asset')));
main.route('someroute', someHandle);
var app = express();
app.use(express.static(path.resolve('./app/asset')));
app.route('someroute', someHandle);
main.use(app);
```

Comment: I tried that, id does not help, but indeed `main.use(express.static(path.resolve('./app/asset')));` is work.  The question is why it won't  work  with subapp (app)

Comment: _Is_ that your question? I think this answer's correct (and germane) given your original post. You may want to look into the `__dirname` "global" as well.

Comment: Does someasset.js exist in both /asset and /app/asset folders?  If so, given how your code is ordered, the static files in /asset will be matched first

Answer (score 1):

Your use case looks like a good candidate for Express Router, which is "an isolated instance of middleware and routes":

http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#router

Specifically, try replacing

```
var app = express();
```

with

```
var app = express.Router();
```

Comment: Thank for answer, but I try use mounted app as described in [http://expressjs.com/ru/4x/api.html#express](http://expressjs.com/ru/4x/api.html#express) app.mountPath